# PrintWriter confusion

Tags: java

I have a question about PrintWriter in Java, here is my code:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.Scanner;


public class Out {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  try{
File a=new File("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/abc.txt");
PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(a);
Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in);


while(c.hasNextInt()){
    out.printf("%d", c.nextInt());
    out.println();
c.close();  
}
out.close();
System.out.println("input written into file successfully!");
   }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
System.out.println("The file not found");


   }
}

   }
```

After I run the program, the content of file abc is lost, then I performed the Scanner function to type 1 2 3 4 5, it shows the erros:

```
    1 2 3 4 5
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.hasNextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.hasNextInt(Unknown Source)
at Out.main(Out.java:17)
```

It is supposed to output:

```
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
```

But it seems that the program cannnot locate the file, I am not sure which part is wrong, please help, cheers!

Comment: why are they done voting you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are  calling `hasNextInt()` method on the closed `Scanner`  object `c` that gives you execption.

so `c.close();` should be outside `while` loop

Comment: Hi there, thank you for u help, yea, it seems that the error message is gone, but when I type 1 2 3 4 5, it has not reponse at all,what result should I expect?

Comment: @WangPeiTheDancer To get response you need to enter a non - integer value ,so that it exit from the loop.For example type input as `1 2 3 4 5 h`

Comment: @WangPeiTheDancer add out.flush(); in your loop, that will print data in the file every loop-iteration

Comment: Thank you Prabhaker, that is great help!

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the `Scanner` object inside the loop itself!

Try putting it outside the loop.

```
while(c.hasNextInt()){
    out.printf("%d", c.nextInt());
    out.println();
}
c.close();
```

Your expected output is:

```
input written into file successfully!
```

And not:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while(c.hasNextInt()){
out.printf("%d", c.nextInt());
out.println();
}
 c.close();
```